# Firefox Nightly does not start due to my mistake

Tags: windows-10, firefox, firefox-profile

I using Firefox Nightly.
I mistaked that start it during updating.

Now, when I start Firefox Nightly, something a window show just a moment then it close immediately.

I tried reset profile from profile manager, safemode, re-installation of Nightly, reboot computer. but this problem is not fix.
Also this problem have happened in safe mode startup.
I don't know why the window display only just a moment.

How do I fix it?

Windows 10 Home 1809

---

#### Edit: Error message of nightly

[image: error message of nightly]

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall Firefox and reinstall?

Comment: I have tried uninstall and delete profile directory in %APPDATA% then reinstall.

Comment: Might be a problem with the Nightly version. Try complete uninstall and see if the stable Firefox version works correctly. If it does, complain to the developers.

Comment: stable works fine, after that I tried re install nightly.
nightly shows something error message like attached picture

Comment: Add a picture that error message of nightly

Comment: It doesn't help to understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Nightly you have accepted the risk of using an unstable version.
Problems such as this one are temporary bugs that are found by volunteers
like yourself and are usually quickly fixed by the developers.

If when participate in the beta-testing of Nightly (actually alpha-version),
you need to communicate problems to the developers, you should do that
through the Firefox website.

The only advice possible from us here, on our site, is for
staying with the stable version that works.
We cannot fix bugs in the code of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is being tracked [here in bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1548990) so there's no need to report it again.

Sometimes nightlies are respun if there's widespread breakage if a fix or backout is implemented quickly enough, otherwise you'd need to use another version of Firefox either the standard release build or Beta.